# Did this scientific experiment on worker/robber roles in pig's behaviour take place?

Tags: social-psychology, animal-cognition

I remember that I read a story of an experiment on pig behaviour in a book when I was a child. I believe that the book was written by Bernard Werber, but I am not 100% certain.

An experimenter put a group of pigs in a cage, in which there is some sort of device that releases food when some work is done (something like rolling a wheel). Some pigs did the work to get the food, and some pigs did not do the work but just stole the food from the pigs that worked.
When the experimenter did the same experiment again with only the pigs that stole other pigs' food, he found that the ratio of worker/robber was almost the same as before. The author used this as an explanation for why we always see workers and exploiters in human societies.

But I cannot find anything about this on the Internet.
Was this experiment even real? Does anyone know about this experiment?